# GSConnect file share failure

Tags: kde-connect

Using Ubuntu 22.04 with GS Connect Gnome extension, I can send files to my Android 14 phone but can't send files of any size from phone to laptop.  The apps are up to date on both devices. I've tried reinstalling on both devices and the firewall is set up correctly.  Also, the phone fails mount via GS Connect.  Can anyone suggest a solution?